# CMS php logon with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, execution

I'm not deeply into MySQL, so I followed a small tutorial about a simple php CMS system. As described here, https://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database

In the article there is a simple user MySQL database generated by:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(100) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

It seemed just what I needed, a simple of login system for simple datalogger site. And for web purposes it would indeed work I believe. Though in my case I have a small datalogger device that should login over C#

```cs
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

When I started to write the connection url

```cs
 MySqlConUrl = $"Server={DBServer};Database={DeviceDB};Uid={Acount};Pwd={AcountPass}";
 MySQLcon = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConUrl);
```

I noticed when I tried to write multiple device databases so a user acount logs on and by userID is allowed/disalowed to see databases. Then C# cannot login to the earlier database, nor can I logon to that user database itself with C#.
And I cannot set permissions with users from the first table. 
Is there a way to make that earlier database support C# logins as well?

**--update 2--as of 18/2/2018**
To clarify a bit more MySQL contains a database \mysqls\users
That's where MySQL internal users are created, only those accounts can be used by the MySQLclient,  MySqlConnection( ) command. What I am looking for a way to use another custom user database, not under \mysql\users. So that it can provide logon functionality for mySQL connectors as used by C#

Comment: The account of MySQL DBMS can't access into `DeviceDB` schema? then you need to grant permission of it to `Acount`.

Comment: Why are you following a PHP tutorial when using C#? That tutorial is also **extremely low quality** and should not be used. Manual escaping is used throughout the code and proper password hashing practices are completely ignored.

Comment: Well php can simply use    MD5(variable) to hash a string. 
They wanted to have it in MySql

Comment: On a side note: `Pwd={AcountPass)}` looks like a typo. Edit: Oh, I guess it was :)

Comment: indeed typo thnx

Comment: pingback, sorry nothing to add but its such an interesting question i'd like to know about any solution to this, basically your asking a mysql internal logon provider based upon a custom user database, other then mysql\users

Comment: Can you clarify your question

Comment: @Yitzchok when using the C# connector for vs2017,  through the name space of   MySql.Data.MySqlClient; to logon to a database, it uses the MYsql internal user database to fulfill logon requests. I'd rather would have another DB to do this, so i can run multiple database solutions under the hood of one mySQL server, then i also be able to move solutions to another server (by copying user logon DB and the DB for that solution).

Comment: It seems like an XY https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Question. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? Are you trying to create a login screen for users?

Comment: I'd like to logon to a specific database using mySQL connectors. And i dont want to logon to msSql's internal logon DB (where the root acount sits).
In php its easy, to fake another DB and use it as login db, when using connectors though this seams not possible, your into C# as well, cause its not a PHP problem.

Comment: @user613326 can you add an example of what you would do in PHP.

Comment: @YitzChock there is no equvalant of PHP, i dont use PHP, i dont compare against "some" table, i'm using the DB connector, which is a verry different thing when coding C#, look at where your root acount is stored, when using a connector only that user DB seams usable thats the problem. I know how to write small simple cms in php thats not the point.

Answer (score 2):

**From the question, this is what I think is going on.**

You are trying to use the *web users* credential (Account and AccountPassword) to make the connection to the database.

This isn't how it works for websites and in the blog post.

Here is how it works

You have a database in MySQL which the application connects to using its own login information which is stored in the connection string and this *doesn't* change depending on the user.

Now when you want to authenticate a user you can check up his login information in the `users` table (while still connecting to the database using **YOUR** connections string).

If you want more information on authentication/authorization check out the [asp.net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)

**Response to comment clarification**

Now let's look at it from a Multi-tenant application perspective.

If you plan on having only one instance of the application running which connects to other databases then you would need a way to get the database information for the tenant. What you can do is create one database that the application connects to and store that connection string in the application settings. It should have a table with all the tenants and the database login information.

If you have an instance per tenant then it would probably be easier to just add the connection string in the web.config, appsettings.json or in an Environment Variable.

**Regarding changing where/how MySQL stores user information**

You can check out [Database Administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ehm no i'm no trying that, i know what you mean.
Though your close mySQL's internal user database, i'd like to use another DB user table (other then buildin) for that  (so the PHP guy may keep his onw) ,but  so that SQL connector based solutions, can have their own DB per solution. Ea I should then be able to move that DB solution to another mySQL server, keeping logons intact. And multiple solutions could then co-exist without harm on the same mySQL server. (without making use of web users for the connector based solutions)

Comment: @user613326 Are you trying to build a multi-tenant solution?

Comment: @user613326 It doesn't look like you can do exactly what you are want to do https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html 'Internally, the server stores privilege information in the grant tables of the mysql database (that is, in the database named mysql).' I think you're looking at the problem from the wrong way.

Comment: hm multi tenant is new term to me but it seems right, essential its about -expandability -moving databases between production and development easily, and moving solution databases around to different hosts / clouds; whiteout moving sql itself, at some point when i was in mysql i got the impression that it would be possible. ea having a huge mySQL server, which could work for various independent software solutions. you might be right that it might not be supported, in that case i'll for another database that does support this.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort you took, the way you describe is not how i ment multi tenant, the essence though is I should look for something else. I needed one server running multiple databases and per datatabase a login, perhaps maybe a docker solution or so..as it comes clear mysql with its connectors cannt do this.

Comment: @user613326 MySQL should allow you to create a user that only has access to one database though that information is stored with MySQL not in that specific database